# What can you do in and what is haram in Oral sex

Tags: sex, sexuality

I would like to know when a person have oral sex and the semen of the man gets into the womens mouth where does  it say it is haram beacuse there is no hadieth or nothing in the Quarn that said that semen is not allowed in a womens mouth.

Answer (score 0):

Assalam o alaikum. Oral sex is makrooh(disliked), not haraam. There is difference within scholars on this matter but it is not mentioned as haraam in Holy Quran Or Hadith. Therefore, you should use your own judgement on this. As from my point of view, it doesn't appeal any goodness or morality, this act doesn't sound good, neither appealing. Rather, it is repulsive. For one's semen to enter one's mouth, doesn't indicate any morality. May Allah(s.w.t), guide us all. Ameen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are no clear evidence in Islam that oral sex is haram.

This is one of the disgusting and filthy things. However to know if it's halal or haram, we need evidence.

This habit was never thought of during that Golden era of the Sahabah radiyallahu anhum (In fact , not even here a few decades ago) so you won’t find hadeeth regarding it. (IslamQA.org)

But the advise from sheikhs are to stay away from these things.
And it's not appropriate for a Muslim to do such things. **Also the mouth and the tongue is for Zikrullah, Tasbeeh, Istighfaar and tilaawat. Also, during oral sex, there is the risk of najaasat on the organs and a risk of it entering the mouth. Also the medical experts attribute many illnesses with this abhorred act.** [islamQA.org](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/tafseer-raheemi/51568)

And I highly recommend you to watch this [**video**](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5j9fS3P2cc)